# Issues in scrollable datatable

Tags: jsf-2, primefaces

I'm facing an issue in scrolling datatable.

If scrolling is disabled, the datatable looks like :
[image]

But when scrolling is enabled, the columns get distorted & look like: 
[image]

Infact the text size also changes.

Any workarounds ? I did have a look on http://code.google.com/p/primefaces/issues/detail?id=3361#makechanges . But is there any other workaround ?

Regards,
Shikha

Comment: Scroll+Grouping not supported at the moment, see the datatable feature compatibility matrix.

Comment: @CagatayCivici Is this issue fixed in 3.3-Snapshot ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As per the comments above, it is not supported currently.

BR,
Shikha